# How to render update in inactive window in electron-app with angular 6?

Tags: angular, electron

I create a multi window electron app with angular 6. When I send and IPC from one window to another, I can get angular to execute functions and change the data model, but I can't make it render the changes. This is even true when I use focus() on the formerly inactive window before I send the IPC and change the data model.

But I think there must be a way to force Angular to render inactive windows. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, just for the record:

I fixed it by changing the changedetectionstrategy to onPush and then including this.ref.detectChanges() to the subscription of my eventEmitter.

But as it still didn't work on one Dom element, namely bs-sortable, I found this comment:
https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/1716
In a nutshell: Don't just change the data for sortable, but manually write the change:

this.sortableComponent.writeValue(myList);

Now everything works fine.